# Better React component hierarchy for rendering progress bar each second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a simple react app that is a music player. It has an album art frame, play/pause button, and a progress bar. The current component structure is  which renders  and .

The state representation:

```
{
            tracks: //array of audio urls
            current: new Audio(tracks[0].url),
            artistName: //str
            trackName: //str
            albumArt: // image url
            playing: true,
            progress: 0,
            duration: 0,
}
```

However, this presents a problem. We need the progress bar to re-render every second to show the track progress. But right now, inside, , I have an event listener:

```
currentTrack.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
            this.setState({
            progress: this.state.currentTrack.currentTime
        });
});
```

But this will cause *every* component to re-render, even though only `progress` has changed in the state.

I thought about putting `currentTrack` inside the `<Controls>` component as its own state, but then the entire controls component will re-render every second. The only other abstraction I can think of is make the progress bar its own component and put currentTrack inside that, but that feels weird. What would be an optimal component structure?

Comment: Are you sure they are rerendering?  React diffs the components and only renders changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ProgressBar React Component and set the state.progress as property. So every time your player update the state.progress your ProgressBar Component will render.

I control that way my file upload progress and it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `shouldComponentUpdate`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

do you have an example you can post where a bit more example is given?